# extend generic class which should be less generic

Tags: java, simplify

I'm reading from the database into 2 classes that have nothing in common in batches.
Each batch is stored later on a batch class that extends ArrayList
Now I need to take each of the objects in each batch and send some of it fields as a JSON over rabbitMQ.

**Code:**

```
public class ObjectA {
  // Some members and methods
}

public class ObjectB {
  // Some members and methods
}

public class BatchA extends ArrayList<ObjectA> {
  // Some methods for ObjecetA
}

public class BatchB extends ArrayList<ObjectB> {
  // Some methods for ObjectB
}

public class EventClass {

    public void sendEvent(final BatchA batch) {
        // send over rabbit
    }

    public void sendEvent(final BatchB batch) {
        // same code as above
    }
}
```

In order to avoid this duplication of code in `EventClass` I've created an interface for both `ObjecetA` and `ObjectB` and a base class for all batches (as shown below).

**Code:**

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    String doSomething();
}

public class ObjectA implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public String doSomethingElse() {
        return "Goodbye, world!";
    }
}

public class ObjectB implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return "Hello universe!";
    }

    public String justDo() {
        return "I'm just doing stuff...";
    }
}

public class BasicBatch<T> extends ArrayList<SomeInterface> {
}

public class BatchA extends BasicBatch<ObjectA> {
    public void doBatch() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(get(i).doSomethingElse());
        }
    }
}

public class BatchB extends ArrayList<SomeInterface> {
    public void doBatch() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(get(i).justDo());
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that this cannot be done (this code doesn't even compile) - but I'm not sure that is the best way to avoid writing the same method in `EventClass` over and over for each batch type

Comment: Your `Basic` class isn't generic, so `Basic<A>` doesn't make sense. `Basic`'s methods use the `SomeInterface` type because that's how `Basic` is declared, so what you want is impossible, but if you describe the problem you are trying to solve by doing this, and post a [mcve], you might get a useful answer. See also http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: So, I'll try to describe it better - I have 2 classes that inherit from ArrayList and having different elements in the lists. both of them need to be cast into json and send over rabbitmq exchange - what I've found out is that basically I have the same code duplicated just because those 2 objects don't have common base class...

In order to solve that I tried to create a common base class (in my code above - `Base`) and except that on the rabbit mq function.

I can give an example - but as i said - it cannot be compiled so...

Comment: _So, I'll try to describe it better_ Don't add question details in a comment. [edit] your question and add the details directly to the question text.

Comment: you're 100% correct - I've edited my question and added an example for the original code + my changes - hope it's clearer now. thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
public <T> void sendEvent(final List <? extends T> batch, Function <T, String> toJson) {
    batch .forEach (value -> {
         String json = toJson (value);
         // send over rabbit
    });
}
```

(I'm writing on a phone, sorry for syntax errors)

Comment: In my specific case what I was looking for was `List<? extends SomeInterface>` thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, the function toJson cannot be called from the context of the lambda - but in my case, that's good enough since I wanted to call `value`'s method

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the where attribute to your class.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by that?